# Does not display form.errors when not valid

Tags: django, django-forms

I use `UserCreationForm` to render registration form in Django.

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):

class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    model = User
    fields = UserCreationForm.Meta.fields
```

The registration view is defined as follows:

```
def register(request):
    form = RegisterForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('/')
    else:
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, 'registration/register.html', context)
```

And the template for this:

```
{% if form.errors %}
<p>Some Errors occured</p>
{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="POST">

  {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }}

  <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

When I submit invalid data, it does not show `<p>Some Errors occured</p>`, but throws 
`Exception Type:    ValueError
Exception Value:

The view myapp.views.register didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.`
which means I have to return HttpResponsein the 2nd if/else statement. The other forms work fine and show form.error messages, except this one. What is the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> form = RegisterForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)

first of all you dont wanna an empty field in your register form so you dont wanna user or None . second you are using request.FILES while you have no FileField in your form . i fixed your form

```
def register(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():

            form.save()
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']

            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)

            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = RegisterForm()

    return render(request, 'registration/register.html',{'form': form})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the last line back one indent, so it is run both in the case that the request is not a POST and also when it is a POST but the form is not valid.